# True if completionhandler is done

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My app is heavily dependent on the data that is coming. I want it to run the activity indicator and disable user interaction on the view while the data is being downloaded.

Is there a way to check or return something when the completion handler is done?

Answer (score 0):

Define a property, which keeps completion handler, and call it when all the data is obtained:

```
var didObtainAllData: (() -> Void)?

func obtainData() {
    ....
    // When data is obtained.
    didObtainAllData?()
}
```

Comment: obtainData is a normal function that runs in different order compared to a completionhandler.

Comment: I cant put `didObtainAllData` inside a completion handler nor outside.

Comment: @bCM I'm sorry, I didn't get what you were trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

```
typealias CompletionHandler = (success:Bool) -> Void

func downloadFileFromURL(url: NSURL,completionHandler: CompletionHandler) {

 **download code**

 let flag = true
```

**true if download succeed,false otherwise**

```
 completionHandler(success: flag)
}
```

**How to use it.**

```
downloadFileFromURL(NSURL(string: "url_str")!, { (success) -> Void in

**When download completes,control flow goes here.**

     if success {

    } else {
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
func processingTask(condition: String, completionHandler:(finished: Bool)-> Void) ->Void {        
}
```

Use

```
   processingTask("test") { (finished) in
        if finished {
            // To do task you want
        }
    }
```